# [PYMONGO]: Passing sockettimeout in a query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
print(db.command({"count":"collection_name",
                          "query": {"col":"col_value"}},
                          {"socketTimeoutMS":12000}))
```

I saw a query in php it passes socket timeout in the query itself.So,I tried the above query in pymongo but it is not working.

Is there any way to pass socket timeout through a query.

Answer (score 2):

You pass the 'socketTimeoutMS' value while initializing the MongoClient object. Something like this:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient(host='your.host.ip.address', socketTimeoutMS=12000)
db = client['db_name']
print(db.command(
    {
        "count":"collection_name", 
        "query": {"col":"col_value"}
    }
))
```